# Is it possible to somehow change the collider points to match sprites during the animation in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, collider

Is it possible to somehow change the collider points to match sprites during the animation in Unity?

I am using the Unity built in animtion recording feature. I would like to change the points of some of my colliders as animation goes, while at the same time I am changing the respective sprites. I was not able to find any solutions so far.

Any ideas how I could do that?

I have a few attempts to overcome the problem.

1. Create a few game objects with the different preset points for the colliders. The solution will work. But it is crazy hard to develop and maintain resources wise. I will have to spend an immense amount of time creating a separate game object with a collider for each frame. And also the maintenance will be very lame. Because I will need to add a wrapper around all the places where I access collider. So that the wrapper would return the currently enabled collider.
2. I can buy the [2DColliderGen](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/sprite-management/2d-collidergen-7540). But I do not want to spend money on that. And also it is not completely what I am looking for, because even with it I will have significant difficulties developing my animations, maintaining my game and extending it.

Comment: Presumably you considered calling [PolygonCollider2D.SetPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.SetPath.html) to set the points on your collider? But overall, I would not recommend doing this. Altering colliders at runtime can be expensive and lead to inconsistent physics (if you modify the shape so that it now intersects an obstacle that it didn't the last time the physics engine checked for collisions, now it has a new mess to clean up in the next physics step). There are often cheaper/more robust ways to get the physics we need - can you explain your application?

Comment: @DMGregory, it must be a very stupid application, but anyway, here it is. When my character goes up the ladder I play animation of climbing up. For that I change my legs sprites and want to change the colliders respectively. I remember that most people consider it a bad idea to have precise colliders in 2D game. :)

Comment: Want to show us the animation? You might be able to get a good approximation with a couple of 2D capsules that you move back and forth through the animation. But yes, I'd say even better would be to not use detailed collisions like that at all.

Comment: @DMGregory, sorry. I don't like how my sprites look right now. So, I am not feeling comfortable sharing them. But I will try your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: @DMGregory, ok. That is definitely not an answer to my question. But your suggestion with playing around with coliders' shapes helped me to improve the precision very good. I just resorted to the animatable properties: scale (e.g. I used -1 scale to change the collider for the head and I scale down colliders when I change legs sprites) and position. For the time being it will be enough for me, because such changes do not impose maintenance overhead. But I will remain the question, because I feel a mess in my current approach. Hopefully I will be able to fix it later.

Comment: Want to edit your question to ask about your root issue "How do I match my collision to my animation" and post the solution you've found as an answer below?

Comment: @DMGregory, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way as of right now to achieve that easily in Unity.

So, in my case I was able to get going with the following:

- for the head I just use the -1 x scale for the collider object. That makes the collider match my mirrored head sprite.
- for the legs I just scale down the collider. That allows me to get a very nice precision.

The solution above does not present any technical debt and is easy to implement with the default animation system in Unity.